# Invalid and/or missing SSL certificate for URL when calling apiclient.discovery.build

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ssl, google-api-python-client

So I'm running my google endpoint locally with `dev_appserver.py`.
I use the API explorer to test the application.

The code I'm using to create the Service, so I can call the API is the following:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build 
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
service = build('speech', 'v1beta1', credentials=credentials)
```

I receive an SSL error (Invalid and/or missing SSL certificate), even though when I access the stated URL via browser it works fine (that is, the green padlock shows up).

I'm not sure what changed, but this was working fine not long ago.

I tried to disable SSL checking, but was unable to.

Full logs below:

```
INFO     2017-01-02 03:12:02,724 discovery.py:267] URL being requested: GET https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/speech/v1beta1/rest?userIp=0.2.0.3
ERROR    2017-01-02 03:12:03,022 wsgi.py:263] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vini/opt/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/home/vini/opt/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/home/vini/opt/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/mnt/b117/home/vini/udacity/cerci-endpoint/api.py", line 28, in <module>
    service = build('speech', 'v1beta1', credentials=credentials)
  File "/mnt/b117/home/vini/udacity/cerci-endpoint/lib/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/b117/home/vini/udacity/cerci-endpoint/lib/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 222, in build
    cache)
  File "/mnt/b117/home/vini/udacity/cerci-endpoint/lib/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 269, in _retrieve_discovery_doc
    resp, content = http.request(actual_url)
  File "/mnt/b117/home/vini/udacity/cerci-endpoint/lib/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1609, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/mnt/b117/home/vini/udacity/cerci-endpoint/lib/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1351, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/mnt/b117/home/vini/udacity/cerci-endpoint/lib/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1307, in _conn_request
    response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/home/vini/opt/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/dist27/gae_override/httplib.py", line 532, in getresponse
    raise HTTPException(str(e))
HTTPException: Invalid and/or missing SSL certificate for URL: https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/speech/v1beta1/rest?userIp=0.2.0.3
```

Any ideas what could be causing this problem?

Do I have to "install" or update the SSL certificates used by python?

Comment: Same getting this issue from today morning.Could be due to year change 2016  ->  2017.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to [App Engine issue 13477](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=13477) it seems that some of the certificates found in `urlfetch_cacerts.txt` that is included in the `App Engine Python SDK` / `gcloud-sdk` expired `2017-01-01`.

As a temporary workaround, you can replace the contents of `<your-cloud-sdk-path>/platform/google_appengine/lib/cacerts/urlfetch_cacerts.txt` with https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

Comment: Deleting the stated certificates indeed solved the problem.
Thank you very much. This was driving me insane.

Comment: Great  @danielx ! It works. Thanks. But I'm surprised they haven't fixed it yet

Comment: Having the same error trying to fetch from LinkedIn API:

`SSLError: Invalid and/or missing SSL certificate for URL: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/`

Updating `urlfetch_cacerts.txt` file does not help.

Comment: @AndreiIvasiuc are you running the latest version of gcloud-sdk and did you restart `dev_appserver.py`? Try `gcloud components update` to update to the latest available version.

Comment: @danielx unfortunately none of mentioned methods helped. It works fine with everything except LinkedIn API. It was working with LinkedIn before but few days back it just started giving this error.

Answer (score 0):

To build on the answer by @danielx for those on macOS, this is what worked for me. The path to the certificates for me was:

```
/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/cacerts/urlfetch_cacerts.txt
```

To update it, I used the following steps:

```
cd /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/cacerts
mv urlfetch_cacerts.txt urlfetch_cacerts.bup
curl -o urlfetch_cacerts.txt -k https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
```

If you don't have `curl` installed, you can manually [download](https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) the certificates an move them to the folder above. 
Don't forget to restart the App Engine dev server if it is already running.

Answer (score -1):

Got this error on local dev environment as recently as Aug 2017. The fix is to update all urlfetch calls and force validation of the certs:

```
urlfetch.fetch(url=url, validate_certificate=True)
```

Did not have to touch the gcloud certs (MacOS). See [Issuing an HTTPS request](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/issue-requests#issuing_an_https_request).

Comment: This didn't fix the problem for me.